# Can one add a custom error in Enum to show valid values?

Tags: python, enums

Let's say I have

```
from enum import Enum

class SomeType(Enum):
    TYPEA = 'type_a'
    TYPEB = 'type_b'
    TYPEC = 'type_c'
```

If I now do

```
SomeType('type_a')
```

I will get

```
<SomeType.TYPEA: 'type_a'>
```

as expected. When I do

```
SomeType('type_o')
```

I will receive

> ValueError: 'type_o' is not a valid SomeType

which is also expected.

My question is: Can one somehow easily customize the error so that it shows all valid types? So, in my case I would like to have

> ValueError: 'type_o' is not a valid SomeType. Valid types are
> 'type_a', 'type_b', 'type_c'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `_missing_` method:

```
from enum import Enum

class SomeType(Enum):
    TYPEA = 'type_a'
    TYPEB = 'type_b'
    TYPEC = 'type_c'
    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        raise ValueError(
                '%r is not a valid %s.  Valid types: %s' % (
                    value,
                    cls.__name__,
                    ', '.join([repr(m.value) for m in cls]),
                    ))
```

and in use:

```
>>> SomeType('type_a')
<SomeType.TYPEA: 'type_a'>

>>> SomeType('type_o')
ValueError: 'type_o' is not a valid SomeType

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: 'type_o' is not a valid SomeType.  Valid types: 'type_a', 'type_b', 'type_c'
```

As you see, it's a little clunky with the exception chaining as Enum itself will raise the "primary" `ValueError`, with your missing error being in the chain.  Depending on your needs, you can narrow the `ValueError` that you are raising in `_missing_` to just include the valid types:

```
from enum import Enum

class SomeType(Enum):
    TYPEA = 'type_a'
    TYPEB = 'type_b'
    TYPEC = 'type_c'
    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        raise ValueError(
                'Valid types: %s' % (
                    ', '.join([repr(m.value) for m in cls]),
                    )
```

and in use:

```
>>> SomeType('type_o')
ValueError: 'type_o' is not a valid SomeType

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: Valid types: 'type_a', 'type_b', 'type_c'
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: This seems to hang indefinitely in Python 3.10.0

Comment: @LucasDurand: I just tested with Python 3.10.0 and it worked fine.  Do you have any details?